# Apple LLVM 5.0 Error: no such file or directory: 'flag' - .pch.pch

Tags: clang, llvm

I am a beginner in objective C and I really need help. When I build for testing I got an `Apple LLVM 5.0 Error`

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'flag'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Here is the code:

> ProcessPCH
>   /Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game-Prefix-bnjwssfqlkergdeubpzrymcefotz/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game-Prefix.pch.pch Original\ Code/Name\ Of\ The\ Game-Prefix.pch
>   normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   cd "/Users/donald/Dropbox/Company/Games/Codes Sources/Original code
>   7.0/NameOfTheGame_v1.0" export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-the -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-the -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
>   -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=4.3 -iquote /Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game.build/Name\ Of\ The\ Game-generated-files.hmap
>   -I/Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game.build/Name\ Of\ The\ Game-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game.build/Name\ Of\ The\ Game-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote
>   /Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game.build/Name\ Of\ The\ Game-project-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -I/Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -I/Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F\\\\"/Users/donald/Dropbox/Company/Games/Codes\ Sources/Original\ Code\ 7.0/NameOfTheGame_v1.0/Original\\\\\\\\
>   Code/SDKs\\\\"\\
>   /Users/donald/Downloads/Tapjoy/Libraries/Tapjoy.embeddedframework\\
>   /Users/donald/Downloads/revmob-ios-sdk\
>   /Users/donald/Dropbox/Company/Games/Codes\\
>   Sources/SDKs/revmob-ios-sdk\
>   /Users/donald/Dropbox/Company/Games/Codes\\
>   Sources/SDKs/TapjoySDK_iOS_v9.1.5/Libraries/Tapjoy.embeddedframework\
>   /Users/donald/Documents/FacebookSDK\
>   /Users/donald/Downloads/pushwoosh-ios-sdk-master-4/Framework\
>   /Users/donald/Downloads/revmob-ios-sdk-3\
>   /Users/donald/Documents/FacebookSDK\
>   /Users/donald/Downloads/pushwoosh-ios-sdk-master-2/Framework\
>   /Users/donald/Downloads/pushwoosh-ios-sdk-master-3/Framework\
>   /Users/donald/Downloads/pushwoosh-ios-sdk-master/Framework -fobjc-arc
>   flag --serialize-diagnostics
>   /Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game-Prefix-bnjwssfqlkergdeubpzrymcefotz/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF
>   /Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game-Prefix-bnjwssfqlkergdeubpzrymcefotz/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/donald/Dropbox/Company/Games/Codes\
>   Sources/Original\ Code\ 7.0/NameOfTheGame_v1.0/Original\ Code/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game-Prefix.pch -o
>   /Users/donald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Name_Of_The_Game-diuaikubsokukmbmgvqiqyfzgbfe/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Name\
>   Of\ The\ Game-Prefix-bnjwssfqlkergdeubpzrymcefotz/Name\ Of\ The\
>   Game-Prefix.pch.pch

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'flag'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Can you help ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post your code? It's a little hard to figure out what the issue is without it.

Comment: Just added complete code, Thanks!

Comment: Hurgh. I'm not reading that command line to find out where you mention a file called `flag`